# Django Development Server doesn't let me start on Homepage

Tags: python, django

I've tried to resolve my problem but didn't succeed. When I start the Development Server from Django, I try to access **http://127.0.0.1:8000/**, but when entered in the Browser it always adds the part /catalog at the end of the URL. I then get an Error (https://i.stack.imgur.com/nd7Pk.png). I know that it should show the site "It worked!". I have tried to delete all projects and reset all settignd I have changed but it still redirects me every time.

Has someone an answer to this problem?

solution: By deleting the browser data about the page it works.

Comment: What is the view that handle `r'^$'` url pattern?

Comment: Thanks Guys it works. I actually didn't do anything and it works again. It didn't redirect me to catalog, but I got some different Errors which I could fix easily. Thanks for taking the time.

Comment: post your view code and url code. the main url and sub url code if you have onr